# User WinWget to keep web site alive in a Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, scheduled-task, wget

I have a site that must stay alive due to a service that runs and check a directory for changes.

The site is running in IIS at a Windows Server 2003 and the solution I came up it that I will Schedule a task that requests the home page every 5 minutes. I am sure that this way the site will stay alive almost all the time.

I have downloaded Wget from [Wget from Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) and I have installed it at my windows server 2003 but I don't know how to use it in order to ping the server but not download anything.

Since I want to use this forever I don't want to save anything on the disk, can you provide me with the command that pings a web page but don't save anything on the disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem,

using `-O -` argument
it will not create a file

`wget -O - -q -t 1 http://www.example.com/`